# Где найти файл статей в OpenCart?

Tags: php, opencart

Нужно найти файл статьи, нужно найти файл,  Там в описание, есть таблицы. Они прописаны не в самом описание, а созданы через Статьи, и подгружаются туда через - [таблица 1] , [таблица 2] и т.п. , нужно найти файл, где может находиться этот скрипт